# How do I find hashtag and tag and url in post in php?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I worked on a project and I'm trying to add the ability to detect hashtags, hashtags and url in a post by php.
I wrote the code but it only returns links How I can return all three together?

```
 public function shortcut_links()
    {

    
    $post_text=   $this->post_text;
      $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
      $tag_text= "/@(\w+)/";
      $hashtag_text= "/#(\w+)/";
    
    if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $post_text, $urls)) {
         foreach($urls[0] as $url){
            
               $post_text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl,'<a href='.$url.' >'. app("bitly")->getUrl($url).'</a>', $post_text);

          }
         
        return $post_text;

    }  elseif(preg_match_all($tag_text, $post_text, $urls)) {
        // make the urls hyper links,
        foreach($urls[0] as $url){
            
               $post_text = preg_replace($tag_text,'<a href='.$url.' >'.$url.'</a>', $post_text);

          }
          return $post_text;

     } 
   elseif(preg_match_all($hashtag_text, $post_text, $urls)) {
         foreach($urls[0] as $url){
            
               $post_text = preg_replace($hashtag_text,'<a href='.$url.' >'.$url.'</a>', $post_text);

          }
          return $post_text;

    } 
  else {
        return $post_text; 
    }
    return $post_text; 


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will currently only replace one type of item due to using `if... elseif...` logic. This means that if one matches - the rest won't be done.

If instead you just used `if...` for each type of item, it will then look for all types.

You would also remove all of the excess `return` statements so that the last thing it does is return the replacements of all of the matches...

```
if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $post_text, $urls)) {
     foreach($urls[0] as $url){
        
           $post_text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl,'<a href='.$url.' >'. app("bitly")->getUrl($url).'</a>', $post_text);

      }
}  
if(preg_match_all($tag_text, $post_text, $urls)) {
    // make the urls hyper links,
    foreach($urls[0] as $url){
        
           $post_text = preg_replace($tag_text,'<a href='.$url.' >'.$url.'</a>', $post_text);

    }

 } 
if(preg_match_all($hashtag_text, $post_text, $urls)) {
     foreach($urls[0] as $url){
        
           $post_text = preg_replace($hashtag_text,'<a href='.$url.' >'.$url.'</a>', $post_text);

      }
}

return $post_text;
```

Also if all of your replacements were the same, then consider putting the various regex's in an array and looping over that (or combining them into 1 regex).

Update:
Some abbreviated code with your example
$post_text= "A dummy message mentioning @ dummyuser and @dummyuser0 and tagged with #dummytag and #dummytag0 you can visit this link: [https://protothema.gr/technology/article/1175500/…";](https://protothema.gr/technology/article/1175500/%E2%80%A6%22;)

```
$reg_exUrl = "/((http|https|ftp|ftps\):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?))/";
$tag_text= "/@(\w+)/";
$hashtag_text= "/#(\w+)/";

$post_text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl,"<a href=\"$1\">" . app("bitly")->getUrl($url) .'</a>', $post_text);
$post_text = preg_replace($tag_text,"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $post_text);
$post_text = preg_replace($hashtag_text,"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $post_text);


echo $post_text;
```

gives...

```
A dummy message mentioning @ dummyuser and <a href="dummyuser0">dummyuser0</a> and tagged with <a href="dummytag">dummytag</a> and <a href="dummytag0">dummytag0</a> you can visit this link: <a href="http">URL</a>s://protothema.gr/technology/article/1175500/…
```

Picking up the URL isn't working very well, but you can read [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) for that.

Comment: It gives me the same result. How can I  putting the various regex's in an array and looping over that (or combining them into 1 regex).

Comment: @Fedaa can you give a sample of the data for me to test this?

Comment: Words containing @ without a space due to  stack overflow site terms .....   
 $post_text= "A dummy message mentioning @ dummyuser and @ dummyuser0 and tagged with #dummytag and #dummytag0 you can visit this link:
https://www.protothema.gr/technology/article/1175500/otto-wichterle-google-doodle-gia-ton-efeureti-ton-fakon-epafis/";

Comment: @Fedaa I've added some abbreviated code with the test text and output